# Rxswift verify password

Tags: swift, model, verify

I'd like to verify my password. However, it is difficult to write code that passes the password to the server and compares it. Next is my code and please tell me how to solve it. The model has a password.

```
 nextBtn.rx.tap
            .map{ self.passwordTxtField.text! }
            .map { DarnerAPI.verifyPassword(pw: $0)}
            .flatMap {request -> Observable<passwordModel> in
                return DarnerAPIClient.shared.networkingResult(from: request)
            }.subscribe { model in
                self.passwordTxtField.text = model.password
                
            }.disposed(by: disposeBag)
```